# Angularjs get object values outside of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get localeData value print out side of below function.
I know how to print in side of function like what i did here.
I have tried this but didn't work.

```
    $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData').success(function(localeData) {
        console.log(localeData);
        }).error(function(err) {
            alert('warning', err.message);
        });
        //need to get that value here.
        console.log(localeData);
```

EDIT

Actually i need to do is this

```
app.factory('customLoader', function($http, $q, SERVER_URL) {

    return function(options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // do something with $http, $q and key to load localization files
        $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData').success(function(localeData) {
         //do something here to localData
        }).error(function(err) {
            alert('warning', err.message);
        });

        deferred.resolve(localeData);
        return deferred.promise;

    };
});
```

This is what i need. finally i need to send localeData.

Comment: You should assign this output to controller's object/variable

Comment: Any idea how to do that ??

Comment: why do you want to print it outside the function?

Comment: Specify your complete scenario, why you want to print it outside the function.

Comment: @SaurabhLprocks Yes done.

Comment: @Madhuranga, I updated my answer to demonstrate how to go about your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't need $q** to accomplish your objective:

```
app.factory('customLoader', ["$http", "SERVER_URL", function($http, SERVER_URL) {
    return function(options) {
        return $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData');
    };
}]);
```

Because `$http` and all it's convenience methods actually return a promise. In this case, you can use this service as follows:

```
customLoader(options).success(function(localeData){
    //do something here to localData
}).error(function(err){
    alert('warning', err.message);
});
```

---

If you really must use `$q`, then this should do:

```
app.factory('customLoader', ["$http", "$q", "SERVER_URL", function($http, $q, SERVER_URL) {
    return function(options) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject){
            $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData').success(function(localeData) {
                //do something here to localData
                resolve(localeData); // ultimately you ought to resolve inside this function
            }).error(function(err) {
                alert('warning', err.message);
                reject(localeData); // ultimately you ought to reject inside this function
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I got a below error.
TypeError: $q is not a function
 

return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

Comment: OK, that's very unlikely. How are you using this service? Meanwhile I made a very minor update to the sample I provided.

Comment: Unfortunately $q is not a function. 
Are you sure is it a function ??
I just copy paste your code.

Comment: It would be best for you if you read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I can't control how and where you paste the code.What version of angular are you using? And I hope you do realise that the factory returns a function?

Comment: yeah i can understand.

Comment: As you understand, if this answer resolved your issue for you or led you to a resolution, then you should select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Meanwhile I've summarised my answer, and my latest addition can help you better.

Comment: But there is a issue with your code.
This return data automatically replaced with null value with in 2 sec. If i use hard coded variable out side of $http.post function it will not replaced .

Comment: You probably should consider sharing your code and its usage with all its relevant context. The samples I shared with you a quite basic, and they should work. Maybe you're integrating them wrongly or using them wrongly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83831/discussion-between-igwe-kalu-and-madhuranga).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create & resolve a defer yourself. There is an easier way. (Also in the example you give, you resolve promise before the underlying ajax completed)

Angular.js `$http` service follows `$q` interface too! So you can write:

```
app.factory('customLoader', function($http, $q, SERVER_URL) {
  return function(options) {
    var promise = $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData')
      .then(function(localeDataBag) {
         var localeData = localeDataBag.data; // .data of 'then' equals to what .success returns.            
         modifiedLocaleData = localeData++;  // do something here to localData
         return modifiedLocaleData; // This is the new result
        })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return $q.reject(err); // This is the new result if something failed. Since we are chaining promises, we should keep failure state.
      });
    return promise;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS is asynchronous, which basically means that your last `console.log` will be executed before your server returned any data. So you have to do it inside both your promises:

```
$http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData').success(function(localeData) {
    console.log(localeData);
    }).error(function(err) {
         console.log(err);
        alert('warning', err.message); //Just in case you didn't know, this line supposes that your server returns a JSON object with a "message"-property

    });
```

That way, your server-response will be `console.log`'ed both on success and failure.

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

## Edit: If you really wanna do it the other way:

```
var response; //First, declare a variable in the parent scope.

$http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData').success(function(localeData) {
    response = localeData; //Assign the response data to the variable.
    console.log(localeData);
    }).error(function(err) {
        alert('warning', err.message); //Just in case you didn't know, this line supposes that your server returns a JSON object with a "message"-property

    });
    console.log(response);
```

The example won't evaluate as you expect, though. The last console.log will just log `undefined`.

Comment: You can use `q` service as well.

Comment: I know how to do that in side the function.

Comment: You have to understand the architecture of JS. Even if you try make it accessible outside the function, thats a sign of an anti-pattern. I'm gonna update my answer to try and let you know how to do it, though.

Answer (score 0):

`localeData` is limited to the scope of `.success` function. You cant get it outside unless you assign it some other variable.

```
var data = ""
$http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData').success(function(localeData) {
    data = localeData;
    }).error(function(err) {
        alert('warning', err.message);
    });
//need to get that value here.
console.log(data);
```

But dont expect to get the desired value in `data` until you get the response back. `$http.post` is **async**

Take a look at **promises** to overcome such issues, because they are used all over the place, in angular world.

**UPDATE:**

As you have done in the  edit, you may either use **$q** service like:

```
app.factory('customLoader', function($http, $q, SERVER_URL) {

    return function(options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // do something with $http, $q and key to load localization files
        $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData').success(function(localeData) {
         //do something here to localData
        }).error(function(err) {
            alert('warning', err.message);
        });

        deferred.resolve(localeData);
        return deferred.promise;

    };
});
```

OR, you may simply return `$http.post` which itself returns a  promise

```
app.factory('customLoader', function($http, $q, SERVER_URL) {
    return function(options) {        
        return $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData');
    };
});
```

In either way, you are returning a **promise** object and not just the actual response you get from server. The `localeData` can be accessed as follows:

```
customLoader().success(function(res){
   console.log(res);
 }).error(function(){
    //show some error message
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

By following way you can access your server response outside factory in the controller:

```
app.factory('customLoader', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            response: {},
            getLocalData: function (param) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.post(SERVER_URL + 'getLocaleData', param).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });


 app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope,customLoader) {

       $scope.GetLocaleData= function() {    
                customLoader.getLocalData({
                    Role: role,
                    Email_Id: $scope.Email,
                    Pwd: $scope.Password
                }).then(function(localeData) {
                    $scope.Data = localeData;                        
                });        
        }
 });
```